# Save multiple WooCommerce custom checkout fields as order meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

Im looking to find some php code that will allow me to extract information (Name, address etc) from the checkout fields and add it to the order meta data.

Looking for this to be a simple as possible

Ive previously found this code which allows a custom box to be added to the checkout page, and I sort of understand how it works, however I want to capture their name when they type it into the billing first name box. I can seem to grasp how to capture this data and put it into the order meta data, Ive tried shortening the code and editing it a few times but I dont seem to be winning

```
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}

/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Phone From Checkout Form').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_phone', true ) . '</p>';
}
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

I like this and it does work but just not in the way i need it to work. thanks for any and all help

Comment: /**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $field[billing_first_name] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'start_date_', sanitize_text_field( $field[billing_first_name] ) );
    }
}
This is the code I created, i want the billing name to copy into order meta data

Comment: Hi, so to clarify, I tried to create some code which would take the value of the billing first name and add it into the order meta data, however my codes doesnt seem to work and I dont understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes and missing things in your code… Try the following replacement code instead:

```
// Add shipping phone (in checkout and My account edit shipping address) and save field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'add_shipping_phone_field' );
function add_shipping_phone_field( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}

// Display shipping phone value on the order edit pages under shipping section
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'display_shipping_phone_in_admin_orders' );
function display_shipping_phone_in_admin_orders( $order ){
    $phone_value = $order->get_meta('_shipping_phone');

    if ( ! empty($phone_value) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Shipping phone').':</strong> ' . $phone_value . '</p>';
    }
}

// Add a custom checkout field
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_slug', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('My custom field'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something… '),
        'required'      => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_slug' ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
// Validate required checkout fields
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( isset($_POST['my_field_slug']) && empty($_POST['my_field_slug']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( '"My custom field" is a required field.' ), 'error' );
    }
}

// Add custom checkout field value as custom order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['my_field_slug']) && ! empty($_POST['my_field_slug']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_slug'] ) );
    }
}

// Display "My field" value on the order edit pages under billing section
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_my_custom_checkout_field_in_admin_orders', 10, 1 );
function display_my_custom_checkout_field_in_admin_orders($order){
    $my_field_value = $order->get_meta('My Field');

    if ( ! empty($my_field_value) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('My field').':</strong> ' . $my_field_value . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now If you need to extract some data from Woocommerce existing checkout fields and combine it in a custom way to save it as custom order meta data, try to be more explicit:

- What fields?
- How you want to combine it?
- What is the custom field slug to be used to save that data combination?

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help, the code is great.
Im trying to use this code and the idea of it to capture data,
Basically, Im using the woocommerce Booking plugin and trying to get the 
start date
end date
the start time
the end time
Which are selected by the customer to be passed into the order meta data so that it can be used for exporting and sorting orders Ive tried a few different variations of code by I dont seem able to do this

Comment: @AlasdairMacEwan Also Note that related minimal booking information is stored in the order as custom order **item** meta data (and not order meta data) and linked to the booking entry… So It's better to ask a new question with all related details in a clear way. You can notify me here.